# Android room database not getting deleted after app uninstall

Tags: android

I am unable to delete the local room database of my app no matter what I do. I tried uninstalling the app to no use. Then I made `android:allowBackup="false"` in AndroidManifest file which didn't help either.

How to delete the app database?

**DB Helper:-**

```
Database(version = 1, entities = [User::class, Cart::class, Purchase::class, Product::class], exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
public abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
    abstract fun cartDao(): CartDao
    abstract fun purchaseDao(): PurchaseDao
    abstract fun productDao(): ProductDao

    companion object {

        private var appDatabase: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            if (appDatabase == null) {
                appDatabase = buildDatabaseInstance(context)
            }
            return appDatabase!!
        }

        private fun buildDatabaseInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            return Room.databaseBuilder(
                context,
                AppDatabase::class.java,
                "consumer_app"
            ).addCallback(object: Callback() {
                override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                    super.onCreate(db)
                    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().execute {
                        getInstance(context).cartDao().insert(Cart())
                    }
                }
            })
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build()
        }
    }
}
```

- Phone - Android 10
- compileSdkVersion 28
- minSdkVersion 21
- targetSdkVersion 28

Comment: show your db helper codes

Comment: @ShahriyarAghajani: Please check now

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
companion object {
    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

    fun getDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
        return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
            val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                AppDatabase::class.java,
                "consumer_app"
            )
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build()
            INSTANCE = instance
            instance
        }
    }
```

Comment: context.applicationContext,